# How to convert PasswordAuthentication to Authenticator in Rhino JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The original Java code is like following,

```
 Session.getDefaultInstance(mailProperties, new Authenticator(){
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(smtp_user, smtp_pass);
}});
```

What modifications are needed to make it work with Rhino Javascript too?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add some more context on what exactly you're trying to achieve? Right now it's hard to answer your question.

Comment: I am trying to create a javax.mail session to send e-mails using javascript, and, and code should be something like  var session = Session.getDefaultInstance (properties, authenticator)  ....